# Automate testing on Lotus Notes 8.5

Tags: testing, automated-tests, lotus-notes

The company I am working is looking for a way to automate functional tests on Lotus Notes 8.5. We have tried different tools including Testcomplete 6 and Rational Robot 7. But we have found issues recognizing objects and implement verifications.

Has anyone try to automate this type of tests? Which tools(approach) you recommend for this?.

I was wondering if it is possible to create code on Domino/LotusScript to automate these tests maybe using agents (have anyone implemented this approach successfully)?

Thanks!

Comment: TestComplete 7 came out recently, which has better recognition for controls, objects, etc. Also they've added an SDK for custom control support. You might have more joy with that?

Comment: I contacted them directly and they respond 

"No.  We probably won’t be a good fit if you need us to work with Lotus notes.  Let me know if there is still interest in TestComplete."

Comment: So far the best approach the team has found is using Domino/Lotus Scripts and Aggents to run automated process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far the best approach the team has found is using Domino/Lotus Scripts and Aggents to run automated test for different process.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet will be AutoUser for Lotus Notes developed by Smart Toucan Software: [Smart-Toucan.com](http://smart-toucan.com/)

It is a full featured automated test tool for Lotus Notes, I'm not aware of any other tool that offers the same functionality.

Comment: Seconded; looks to be the best bet for truly testing client apps.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a LONG time since I've done any Notes development, but since Notes already has a rich API for using Java, why not just use JUnit?

There's even a plugin to output the results of tests to a Document:

http://www.junit.org/node/205

Also, here's someone's attempt to write something a little more customized for Domino testing:

http://palmerweb.blogspot.com/2007/12/sntt-unit-testing-in-domino.html

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the tools you've tried I guess that you want to test the UI rather than the inner details of the code.

I haven't done development for Notes 8, but if it is anything like R7 **I definately think you should look for a non-Notes tool** for testing Notes application UIs. The Notes UI classes is filled with strange gotchas, and I think you will run into problems expressing things like switching tabs, moving around in the document, triggering hotspots, verifying visibility of messages and dialogs, agent runs et.c.

My initial idea was to implement tests in [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/), but I assume the tools you have tried are more friendly for testing and equally competent at recognizing and interacting with window elements.

If you find something that works out, I'd love to hear about it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Rational Robot is a supported program anymore. [Rational Functional Tester](http://www.ibm.com/software/awdtools/tester/functional/index.html) is the latest incarnation and it may be what you are looking for. It will work at the GUI level.

The issue with GUI level testing is that it's not performance testing. One machine drives 1 GUI. Question was about functional testing, so I assume this is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called TestDrive from Original Software, which claims to have support specifically for Lotus Notes client application testing. I don't have any experience with the tool. Their site is at http://www.origsoft.com/products/testdrive/

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing XPages applications, I believe you can use those popular test frameworks like: JUnit, WebDriver, and even Concordium.